# To associate entity with other or not in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Q1. I am not sure when I should associate entity and when I should not.**

eg: Hibernate association by collection

```
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String firstName;
 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
 
    ...
}


@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;

    ...
}
```

OR by just ids

```
@Entity
public class Author {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String firstName;

    ...
}


@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    private Long authorId;

    ...
}
```

**Q2. When using bidirectional association,**

eg: book class

```
@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
 
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "authorId", unique=true)
    private Author author;

    ...
}
```

book always has author which is unique accross books entity,

But since we are lazily fetching, I am not able to use it in hashcode.
I have only `authorId` as unique way to identify record uniquely for equals and hashcode.
How can I handle in this case.

Answer (score 0):

## To answer your first question:

> Q1. I am not sure when I should associate entity and when I should not.

### Arguments for

The short answer is always use associations. In the example you provided, it seems obvious that both entities are related to the same domain.

1. If you use an id in this case, you would lose the constraints the persistence provider (Hibernate) applies to these relationships - i.e. the provider wouldn't know if the value `Book.authorId` used corresponds to an `Author.id` or not. Sure, you could enforce this constraint in a database level, but, then, the persistence mappings wouldn't represent your database constraints.
2. If you consider the entity on the other side of the association too complex to be eagerly retrieved, you can use the `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` hint.
3. For better and for worse, it enforces - or, at least, it should enforce - one to think carefully about his model. Are all relationships bidirectionals? If not, you should not use associations in that entity.

### Arguments against

1. The entities are part of different domains. It depends on your model, but sometimes it doesn't make sense that a persistence context holds entities from different domains. In this case you are probably better creating a value-object to represent the other domain entity's id, i.e. `AuthorId` and map it as an `@Embedded`.

## To answer your second question

> Q2. When using bidirectional association

If you consider `Object#equals` and `Object#hashCode` contracts for an entity class, the only properties that should play a part in these methods should be the ones that are part of its id definition.

Two books instances with the same `Book.id` (the same entity) should always return the same hash. If you use the `Book.author` or `Book.authorId` to generate the hash this wouldn't be the case.

Nevertheless, even if you use the `Book.author` property in `Book#hashCode` method, it wouldn't be a problem if the `Author` entity is lazily retrieved. Once the `Book#hashCode` method is called, the `Author` entity would first the retrieved (and, in sequence, its `Author#hashCode` method would be called).